# Can't push framework's Info.plist

Tags: ios

I generated `Charts.xcframework by Carthage locally.` And added this framework file into my project root folder to track it.

All works fine locally. The framework path is `Myproject/Myproject/Frameworks/Charts.framework`

[image]

But when I want to push them into remote repository I found `Info.plist` of the framework is missing. If I copied that file it can be pushed.

**No Info.plist** in bitbucket repository if there is only `Info.plist` file..
[image]

**Has Info copy.plist** only when has both `Info copy.plist` and `Info.plist`.
[image]

I didn't add any ignore in the .gitignore file of Info.plist.

Not sure why bitbucket just not tracking the `Info.plist` in the `Charts.framework`. Any help, thanks.

Comment: @BorisNikolic It's a bit long time story, I can't remember correctly. Suggest use xcframework or SPM could be solve such issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds  like you are having trouble pushing the `Info.plist` file of the `Charts.framework` to your remote repository on `Bitbucket`. It appears that the `Info.plist` file is not being tracked by `Bitbucket`, even though you have not added any ignore rules for it in your `.gitignore` file.

check if that `Info.plist` file is being ignored by a global `.gitignore` file or by a `.gitignore` file in a parent directory. You can check for global ignore rules by running the command `git config --get core.excludesfile`. If a `global ignore file` is being used, you can check its contents to see if it contains any rules that might be causing the `Info.plist` file to be ignored.

Another  check - see if `Info.plist` file was previously added to the repository's `.gitignore` file and then removed. In this case, you may need to run the command `git rm --cached <file>` to remove the file from the repository's index and then add it back using `git add <file>`.
Some [useful sources](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/push-code-to-bitbucket/) here .

Comment: I unfortunately cant reproduce this now, but I think your answer is very helpful.